# вход на сайт

Tags: веб-программирование, auth

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в программе я мог ввести логин и пароль от определённого сайта и программа при этом авторизировалась там. Как это сделать?

Comment: что за ЯП?

Answer (score 1):

Вроде достаточно послать такой же запрос с данными из программы. Т.е. отследить фаербагом (например) как передаются логин и пароль. Правда скажу честно, не знаю как при этом будет работать сессия, зачастую необходимая для авторизации.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря на чем пишешь. Предположим есть сайт "Мой сайт" с логином "Login" и пароль "PASS", ты открываешь свою программу, вводишь логин и пароль, затем при нажатии ОК, отправляй эти данные в php запросе на сайт "Мой сайт".

Answer (score 0):

Авторизация происходит посредством Post Get запросов.

Язык Программирования = Delphi ?

Заходишь в поисковик и ищешь "Авторизация на сайте Delphi" и получаешь большое количество разъяснённых примеров с использованием компонентов idHTTP, Indy.